# See separate Icon for each browser tab in the windows taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, chrome, web-browser, microsoft-edge

I am looking for a tool that allows the windows taskbar to show my browser tabs as if they were icons.

Something like:

[ windows button | windows applications | browser tabs | time and icons ].

Does this tool exist?

Comment: Could you simply open each page in a new window instead of a new tab?

Comment: I'm more looking for something that keeps the browser as a single application but displays the tabs (and the corresponding icons) separately. Somewhat of a tightly integrated style software that helps thin the line between my browser and the OS